# Unable to load Posts list & Getting error 500 error

Tags: debug, troubleshooting, internal-server-error

List of `Posts` & `Events` doesn't load. Can't publish new either. `Pages` work fine. There was another error too which are now ignored using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32860981/1463443

I tried by disabling all plugins. But the issue isn't there I suppose!

Attaching few screenshots.

**Error on posts list**

[image: Error on posts list]

**Error after trying to add new Post / Event**

[image: Error after trying to add new Event]

Comment: Have you modified the WP Core files? You should take a fresh copy of the latest WordPress and replace the files

Comment: No, nothing was changed on core files. I'll try by replacing core files.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot @TomJNowell, that solved the issue. Reuploaded the files & voila. Why suddenly a working site shows those errors? What may have caused it? I'm using AWS.

Comment: Lots of reasons, security breaches, failed updates, deliberate modifications, who knows